# Reading and writing to a custom config in c#

Tags: c#, configuration-files

Is there a lib in c# that will allow you to read and write to a config or some kind of profile?

I am not talking about the app.config but more like a custom.config similar to the ol .ini file where there were built in lib/functions to read/write to the profile.

I can of course write my own, but would like to know if there exists some common lib or ways to do this...

I know about custom config section but would prefer not to take that route.

Solution

I found what I am looking for. This will work:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14465/Specify-a-Configuration-File-at-Runtime-for-a-C-Co

Answer (score 9):

I would have my custom config as a `class` and then use the `XmlSerializer` to read and write the config values.

```
public class MyConfig
{
    const string configPath = @"...";

    public string Setting1 { get; set; }
    // ...

    public static MyConfig Load()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyConfig));
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(configPath))
            return (MyConfig)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyConfig));
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(configPath))
            serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. That is what I am about to do. But it would seem that this type of thing is done all over the place.  I have an app that read from the app.config that has a custom config section. the customer config section can have multiple definition that is read by mulitple instance of a class that is threaded.  I am having problem using the custom config section because each thread is trying to write to the same app.config.. I would prefer that each thread write to its own define config. but still read some basic setting from app.config

Comment: I found a solution that will work: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14465/Specify-a-Configuration-File-at-Runtime-for-a-C-Co

Comment: Fine by me if the solution works for you.  BUT you did say in question not to use the app.config file.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is really simple key-value pairs (like an old .ini or .cfg file), there's  also local storage from ApplicationData.Current:

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["test"] = "Setting Value"; 
string t = (string)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["test"];
```

However this is tied to a single application, not sure how well it would handle the multiple threads  / multiple instances issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why don'y you just use the settings designer (`Settings.settings` file in your project)?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone does need to save changes to a custom config file (in this instance for a config file with the same name as the dll assembly):

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".dll.config";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

//... make modification (as you would for any app.config, etc...)

config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```